# Themes, Styles, Images not working on MAMP local dev WP site

Tags: php, css, database, wordpress, mamp

My recently downloaded-to-MAMP WP site is not displaying any CSS, styles, themes, or images. The live site broke after a PHP upgrade. After some panicking, I downloaded the WP site (all files, manual installation, FTP download) and exported the database. After a lot of trial and error, I got it just about running on the MAMP localhost, with PHP back at 5.6 (site broke on 7.0).

I did not install Wordpress directly, simply the root directory from the live server in the MAMP localhost folder. The site is displaying the text, line breaks, paragraph breaks, and image holders, but no styles or grid or anything  - bare HTML.

A quick check with the inspector shows that the image-holders are pointing to the correct path for images, and the images are in the relevant folder in Uploads.

I tried deleting all plugins from `wp-options`, and changing themes in the database too.

I can't access wp-admin either - too many redirects. The site is obviously connecting to the database, styles.css is in place, the theme is named correctly, I have tried reverting to twentyfourteen too. No joy. Any thoughts? I can't move it back to the original server space now either and revert to the older PHP either.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Full backup of any state of your Site? Did you check wether the PHP versions of Mamp and WordPress match exactly? Try to install a clean version WordPress on Mamp and then insert the databases. Don’t forget to change your WP config file to the local host address that MAMP is using.